# What does it mean to prove that the addition of two countable sets is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How Should I prove that $\mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set? I've already proven that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: How do you prove union of two countable sets is countable?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik This is not the union of countable sets, but the product. As for the question: can you prove that $\Bbb N + i\Bbb N$ is countable?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If it is the product then I can prove it. But how do we know it isn't the union?

Comment: @Arthur I did not mean this is union of two countable sets.. i was just giving some way...

Comment: So you know how to prove product of two countable sets is countable? @wutangclan

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable, it follows that $i\Bbb{Q}$ is countable as well (since $i\Bbb{Q} = \{ iq : q \in \Bbb{Q}\}$, whereby $\Bbb{Q}$ and $i\Bbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality).

And if you know that these two sets are countable, then by definition there exists a bijection between $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$, and there exists a bijection between $\Bbb{N}$ and $i\Bbb{Q}$.

And you know that $\Bbb{Z}$ is countable and in Bijection with $\Bbb{N}$ as well, so you can set up a bijection between $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ $\cup$ $i\Bbb{Q}$ easily, like this:

Take $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ $\cup$ $i\Bbb{Q}$. If $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, then map $x$ to its counterpart in $\Bbb{N}$ according to the bijection you know that exists. If $x \in i\Bbb{Q}$, then map $x$ to its counterpart in $\Bbb{N}$ according to the **other** bijection you know exists. Let that counterpart be $v$. Map $v \in \Bbb{N}$ to $-v \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Now you're mapping the $\Bbb{Q}$ part of $\Bbb{Q}$ $\cup$ $i\Bbb{Q}$ to the positive part of $\Bbb{Z}$, and you're mapping the $i\Bbb{Q}$ part to the negative part of $\Bbb{Z}$. And you're done.

You can make this proof a lot more elegant or short, but I tried to be clear. You'll also have to deal with the case of which element in  $\Bbb{Q}$ $\cup$ $i\Bbb{Q}$ maps to $0$ (this is easy -- you'll just have to declare what it maps to, and adjust your bijections slightly, like by shifting one map over by $1$ -- e.g. if $q \in \Bbb{Q}$ mapped to $n$, map it to $n+1$ or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I wanted to express what you wrote as a function, what would that look like?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if we should be dealing with the union, instead of the product of the two sets.

Comment: @wutangclan just make a bipartite function $f(x)$: if $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ then $n$, otherwise $-n$

Comment: @wutangclan do you mean the cartesian product of the sets?

Comment: Yes, I think we ought to be showing that $| \mathbb{Q} \times i \mathbb{Q}|$ is the cardinality of the set.

Comment: @wutangclan Ah. You should amend your question post appropriately.